# Two consecutive Participes Passé in the expression « j’aurais eu tôt fait de ... »

Tags: grammaire, expressions-idiomatiques, temps-surcomposés

> 1: Si je n’avais pas perdu bêtement la bague de fiançailles, j’**aurais eu tôt fait** de lui demander sa main.

I’m not sure why the use of two consecutive Participes Passé, « eu » et « fait », is considered grammatical. It’s part of a set expression, to be sure, but still ...

It’s tempting to drop « eu » and say:

> 2 : Si je n’avais pas perdu bêtement la bague de fiançailles, j’**aurais tôt fait** de lui demander sa main.

But I assume that in this specific expression, « aurais tôt fait » is actually the ***Present*** Conditional rather than the seemingly Past Conditional, which changes the meaning of the main clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bien que rare, c'est grammaticalement correct. Il s'agit un conditionnel passé surcomposé.

[Questions de langue - Temps surcomposés - Académie française:](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#86_strong-em-temps-surcomposs-em-strong)

> Tout aussi rares sont les autres temps : conditionnel passé surcomposé (quand elle aurait eu fait cela ; quand elle aurait été partie)

---

> j’aurais eu tôt fait de lui demander sa main.

est équivalent à:

> je lui aurais aussitôt demandé sa main

Comment: Wow, I hadn't expected there to be an official term for this! Am I correct in thinking that the 2nd example with « j'aurais tôt fait de » actually represents the **present** conditional, despite appearances to the contrary? Merci.

Comment: Also: Do the 1st and 2nd sentences both work, depending on the meaning intended?

Comment: "C'est grammatical bien que rare" ne me semble pas très français...

Comment: @AlFoиceѫ Pas faux, il manquait au moins une virgule. Je l'ai réécrit de manière plus orthodoxe.

Comment: Hi. What's your take on using this expression in casual speech/writing?

Comment: This expression is very formal and literary; it can't reasonably appear in casual usage.

Answer (score 3):

Une expression idiomatique:
**Avoir tôt fait de** + inf. Ne pas mettre longtemps à. Synon. usuel avoir vite* fait de (This is from the CNRTL site)/

To not take long to do something, to quickly do something.

To change the tense of the expression, you work with AVOIR and leave "tôt fait de" unchanged.

Comment: Please do not edit. I like it the way I had it. Thank you, Let people discover the CNRTL site for themselves.

Comment: downvoters: tsk, tsk