# Whether to say “il a eu vite fait de repartir” or “il a vite fait de repartir”

Tags: expressions, temps-grammatical

> Il cherchait quelqu’un, mais il n’y avait pas une seule cliente, alors il **a eu vite fait** de repartir.
>
> Il cherchait quelqu’un, mais il n’y avait pas une seule cliente, alors il **a vite fait** de repartir.

I waver between the two. I wonder if I can use the first construction if I see « vite fait » as an adverbial phrase instead of « fait » as the past participle directly related to the subject « il ». In which case, it makes sense to say « a eu », after all.

But then, another question arises: How does the first construction compare to the second where « (a) fait » serves as the *Passé composé* this time, with just « vite » being the adverb.

In a nutshell, I'm not sure which I should consider to be the past participle of the the *Passé composé*: « (a) **eu** » in the first or « (a) **fait** » in the second.

Comment: « Il a fait de repartir », to take the phrase at its simplest? It may be that I'm out of touch with how people talk with my overly scholastic French, but how could « faire de *inf.* » be grammatical in the first place? I could be entirely on the wrong track, but what if you compared « Il a eu vite fait repartir » and « Il a eu vite repartir » or something along those lines if you want to test whether *vite fait* can work as a single lexical item?

Comment: @LukeSawczak Hi. I know where you're coming from on this one, but no matter which of the two is the generally accepted form, the preposition « de » in this idiomatic turn of phrase cannot be omitted in any case, I believe. ;)

Comment: Hmm! Well, I'll be watching this thread to see what I can learn, then...

Comment: As a French native, I would definitely say "il a eu vite fait de repartir" but I have no idea why. My gut feeling is that "il a vite fait de repartir" sounds really weird if not incorrect.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Actually, I use "avoir vite fait de" as a more casual variant of "avoir tôt fait de" where the use of "tôt" gives it a rather literal flavour.

Comment: Dans la locution verbale *avoir vite fait*,  *vite fait* ne change jamais quel que soit le le temps. *Il a (vite fait)* est le présent (a). Il a eu (vite fait) est le passé composé, auxiliaire avoir suivi du participe passé *eu*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Avoir vite fait de* est une locution verbale équivalente à *avoir tôt fait de* qui n'est plus très utilisée. Voir [Two consecutive Participes Passé in the expression « j’aurais eu tôt fait de ... »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23916/two-consecutive-participes-pass%C3%A9-in-the-expression-j-aurais-eu-t%C3%B4t-fait-de)
L'expression *avoir vite fait de* est figée.  Ici, le mot *faire* n'a pas valeur de verbe au sens où il ne sera jamais conjugué. De même, *vite* ne pourra pas être supprimé : *il a fait de partir* n'a pas de sens.

Comment: Hi. I feel there is a significant difference between the two: The phrase "tôt fait" is exclusively used for the expression "avoir tôt fait de", while "vite fait" can stand on its own as an adverbial phrase and be used outside of the expression "avoir vite fait de". Which has prompted this question. :)

Comment: @Alone-zee  *Il a vite fait de repartir* équivaut à *Il ne tarde pas à partir*.

Comment: @Laure justement, je me posais la question : la 2nde phrase est-elle correcte ? *Avoir vite fait* y est au présent alors que le reste est au passé...

Comment: Pour moi  seule la première est correcte.

Comment: @Alone-zee : oui mais "faire de partir" ne veut rien dire, même vite :) ou alors je vous ai mal compris...

Comment: @Laure : nous sommes d'accord.

Comment: @Alone-zee : *il a très tôt fait son lit* est correct. Anyway, I've updated my response.  Sorry, I first wrote a longer answer but when I saw the discussion about *avoir tôt fait de* I shortened it. Obviously a bad idea.

Comment: @Laure Now I wonder if the *present* construction "il a vite fait de repartir" is acceptable, depending on context? Also, am I correct in assuming that even in "il a vite fait de repartir", the adverb is "vite fait", not "vite"?

Comment: @Alone-zee I would not use the present in your sentence, it clashes because of time agreement.  I would not call *vite fait* an adverb. French grammar calls *(avoir) vite fait de* "locution verbale".